# Ruby - Random number in range with exceptions

Tags: ruby, exception, random

I have a series of random numbers for a lottery.

How can i chose the random number for the second place and so on, without having the risk of pulling out the first place again?

```
$first = rand(0..99999)
$second = rand(0..99999)
$third = rand(0..99999)
```

I need to get some sort of exception in the following drawings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`shuffle` will permute the entire array, which is potentially slow for large arrays. [`sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) is a much faster operation

```
(1..99999).to_a.sample(3)
```

For benchmarking purposes:

```
> require 'benchmark'
> arr = (0..99999).to_a; 0
> Benchmark.realtime { 10_000.times { arr.sample(3) } }
=> 0.002874
> Benchmark.realtime { 10_000.times { arr.shuffle[0,3] } }
=> 18.107669
```

Comment: Sure, but if the time is an issue he really should not allocate an array of a million integers to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

If you are picking out a very small number of numbers from a large array it might be smart to just get 3 random numbers and the check that they are different:

```
def create_array_and_pick_three
  arr = (0..99999).to_a
  arr.sample(3)
end

def get_three_random_until_uniq
  array, num = [], 3
  array = (1..num).map{rand(0..99999)} until array.uniq.size == num
end


p Benchmark.realtime { 1000.times { create_array_and_pick_three }} #=> 4.343435
p Benchmark.realtime { 1000.times { get_three_random_until_uniq }} #=> 0.002
```

Exactly what is faster for you depends on the size of the array and the number of random numbers you need.

Comment: This is certainly clumsier to code than the other answers, but for picking a few numbers out of such a large set it is definitely the correct algorithm.